# In Unity3D/2D Mouse released outside is not possible?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mouseevent

I am developing UI for my game. I started with simple Play button.

When it is touched, the game will start, but if the user touches the play button and releases touch outside the play button nothing should be happen.

How to implement such action. I tried with following code, but else statement in OnMouseUp never executes.

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {

    hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);

    if(hit) {

        if(transform.name == hit.transform.gameObject.name) {

            Debug.Log("Button touched");
        }
    }
}else
if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {

    //hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);

    if(hit)    {

        if(transform.name == hit.transform.gameObject.name) {

            Debug.Log ("touched up over same button.");
        }else {
            Debug.Log ("touched up not over same button.");
        }
    }
}
```

Is it such that whenever MouseDown is fired MouseUp on that button will always be fired unless other collider of another game object is under touched?

In unity forum I have been suggested to use UI element on this thread [Mouse released outside is not possible?](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/mouse-released-outside-is-not-possible.321732/)

But if we want to apply same behaviour for game objects then what?

Comment: What behaviour are you currently getting? Does "Button touched" ever get written to the debug log?

Comment: I get button touched. But what I want is, If user released touched outside the button an action on touch button should not get executed. I hope you understood? In short it's about touch released outside.

Comment: Yes I understand, I just wanted to check whether your Raycast was working. Have you tried removing the first `else`? If the mouse button was going down and up in the same frame (which seems unlikely) then you'd get the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: Yes. I added `else` later. No matter what I never got "touched up not over same button." in log.

Comment: Have you tried adding a Debug.Log statement somewhere in the second `if` block, but outside the `if(hit)`? I'm trying to work out how far it gets.

Comment: I get all `Debug.log` accordingly, except the last one `Debug.Log ("touched up not over same button.");` in both state - touch over and touch released outside. One thing we can do is adding box colliders to each game object including background sprite, but it looks really impractical that we have to add Collider to all game objects only to detect touch released outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for a way to not only detect when the mouse button is released over the GameObject, but also when it is released anywhere that is not over the GameObject. You shouldn't have to add Colliders to everything else in the scene to detect this.

In your second `if` block, you're logging in the case where the ray hit something and the thing it hit wasn't the GameObject in question. There's also the case where the ray hit nothing:

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {

    hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);

    if(hit && transform.name == hit.transform.gameObject.name) {
        Debug.Log ("touched up over same button.");
    } else {
        Debug.Log ("touched up not over same button.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for u r kind help. I got it working with the same correction. My bad I was not understanding it correctly. Previously I already tried it (w/o commenting hit) but don't know what went wrong. Anyway, thanks for help.